# Count occurrences if cell is not null

Tags: sql-server, dynamic, count

I have a table as shown below:

```
Code   Aug-19   Sep-19  Oct-19  Nov-19  Dec-19  Jan-20  Consistency
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ABC     NULL    501.2   584.56  NULL    NULL    NULL        NULL
DEF     NULL    NULL    NULL    260.4   222    323.77       NULL
```

I need to take the occurrences in the months column and update the consistency column as

```
Code   Aug-19   Sep-19  Oct-19  Nov-19  Dec-19  Jan-20  Consistency
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ABC     NULL    501.2   584.56  NULL    NULL    NULL        2
DEF     NULL    NULL    NULL    260.4   222    323.77       3
```

The columns [Aug-19],[Sep-19]... are dynamic which will change month on month.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You might have to use ugly `CASE` expressions here:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET Consistency = CASE WHEN [Aug-19] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
                  CASE WHEN [Sep-19] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
                  CASE WHEN [Oct-19] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
                  CASE WHEN [Nov-19] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
                  CASE WHEN [Dec-19] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
                  CASE WHEN [Jan-20] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```

Note that having the need to do this is a serious sign that your database table design is not optimal.  It would be much better to just maintain a single date column.  Then, obtaining the non `NULL` count for every code would just require a typical `GROUP BY` operation.  Consider a table looking something like the following:

```
Code | Date         | Val
ABC  | '2019-08-01' | NULL
ABC  | '2019-09-01' | 501.2
ABC  | '2019-10-01' | 584.56
ABC  | '2019-11-01' | NULL
ABC  | '2019-12-01' | NULL
ABC  | '2029-01-01' | NULL
DEF  | '2019-08-01' | NULL
DEF  | '2019-09-01' | NULL
DEF  | '2019-10-01' | NULL
DEF  | '2019-11-01' | 260.4
DEF  | '2019-12-01' | 222
DEF  | '2029-01-01' | 323.77
```

Now you only need this query:

```
SELECT
    Code,
    COUNT(Val) AS Consistency
FROM yourNewTable
GROUP BY
    Code;
```

Comment: Please consider abandoning your current approach in favor of a much better table design.  See my answer for more information.